# Algorithm to Compare Price of Sorted List

Tags: java, python, arrays, algorithm, compare

So today, I want to implement a program (java or python) that compares elements of two sorted array of food items and outputs the lowest price of the item out of the two arrays.

The array will be in the form {{name, price}}. There will be two of these arrays to compare from. This might not seem very clear, so here's some code:

Array 1: `{{"Apple" 4.5}, {"Banana" 3.1}, {"Dragonfruit", 5.2}, {"Dorian", 1.5}}`

Array 2: `{{"Apple", 3.1}, {"Dragonfruit", 4.5}}`

Output: `{{"Apple", 3.1}, {"Dragonfruit", 4.5}}`

As you can see here, the 2 arrays are sorted by name in alphabetical order. The 2 arrays do not have to be the same length either. So in summary, it should:

1. Compare the name of the item first, if they are the same:
2. Output the one that costs less.

I heard somewhere that this is a type of cosequential sorting? I have searched this word before but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Try to find a solution by yourself and if you have a concrete problem with your implementation, come back and we'll help you with your concrete problem. Stack Overflow is not the place to build your code.

Comment: what does it mean "java or python"? you want us to decide for you? why not other languages? in short, first step is to decide on the programming lang

Comment: Choose your language first.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code so we can debug.

Comment: What about Banana and Dorian? Do you only want fruits that exist in all lists? Is your input a list of list in the respective language, or a string that needs to be parsed first?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenete the two lists and sort them lexicographically, first on the name, then on the price in case of ties.

Then it suffices to output the records that are followed by the same name.

```
{"Apple", 3.1}
{"Apple", 4.5}
{"Banana" 3.1}
{"Dorian", 1.5}} 
{"Dragonfruit", 4.5}
{"Dragonfruit", 5.2}
```

This works for more than two lists.

Comment: Updated, my previous version was outputting all distinct items.

Answer (score -1):

public class TestDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Fruit> list1 = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    List<Fruit> list2 = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    List<Fruit> list3 = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    list1.add(new Fruit("Dragonfruit", 5.2));
    list1.add(new Fruit("Dorian", 1.5));
    list1.add(new Fruit("Apple", 4.5));
    list1.add(new Fruit("Banana", 3.1));
    Collections.sort(list1);
    list2.add(new Fruit("Dragonfruit", 4.5));
    list2.add(new Fruit("Apple", 3.1));
    Collections.sort(list2);
    for (Fruit fruit1 : list2) {
        for (Fruit fruit2 : list1) {
            if (fruit1.getName().equals(fruit2.getName())) {
                if (fruit1.getPrice() <= fruit2.getPrice()) {
                    list3.add(fruit1);
                } else {
                    list3.add(fruit2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list3);
}
```

}

public class Fruit implements Comparable {

```
private String name;
private Double price;
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {

    return this.name.compareTo(fruit.name);
}
```

}

Comment: This is pretty inefficient and fails in case of equal prices.